# Making an ssh ControlPath connection act as slave-or-fail (not fallback to ControlMaster)

Tags: ssh, automation, openssh

I'd like to force secondary ssh connection(s) to use an existing ControlMaster connection and **fail** if the master is not present.

With `ssh -o ControlPath=somewhere -o ControlMaster=no ...` this new connection will look for the existing master, and if not found, fall back to creating it's own standalone connection.  Can we just disable the fallback?

The closest thing that I can come up with is

```
ssh -o ControlPath=somewhere -o ControlMaster=no -O check \
    && ssh -o ControlPath=somewhere -o ControlMaster=no
```

Am I missing something?

### Why?

A common-for-me case is where `ssh` requires some interaction with an OTP, or hardware thingy.  I typically work with several terminals, each running something like `while sleep 1; do ssh-and-reconnect-to-a-screen-session ; done`.

In my perfect world there would be a single master connection (with OTP/token check) then every other terminal would loop&fail until they could piggyback across the control master connection.

As it is (depending on the ~random order that previous connections fail-and-retry), opening my laptop lid spams me with several OTP/token checks at once because every `ssh` command wants to be the/a new master.

(Again in a perfect world `mosh` would solve the pick-up-where-I-left-off issue, but here that isn't really an option)-:

Comment: I considered `-L 2222:localhost:22` on the "master" connection, then setting the slaves to use `-p 2222`, but I think that gets me further down the TCP-over-TCP flow-control rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is really specific. I don't think you miss something.

There are only few more command-line switches `-S` and `-M` that you can make use of, if you don't want to put that into the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ssh -S somewhere -O check host && ssh -S somewhere -M host
```

Comment: Right, -M/-S are nice short cuts.   Thanks for the 2nd look.